# process.env.VARIABLE is undefined in webpack/docker/heroku deployment

Tags: node.js, heroku, docker, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I am having some issues getting my app to read the heroku environment variables. The application itself is a node.js react/redux web application ran with webpack-dev-server, deployed in a Docker container which is hosted on Heroku.

I'm setting the variables in a `config.js` file, which are to be used through the app:

```
module.exports = {
    baseUri: process.env.BASE_URI || "http://localhost:8000",
    baseApiUri: process.env.BASE_API_URI || "http://localhost:8080",
    port: process.env.PORT || 8000
}
```

In my index.tsx file I am trying to make a simple get request to the baseApiUri, but am finding that it is defaulting to localhost even though I have these variables as settings in Heroku.

I am getting these results both:

- locally when I run 
  `set BASE_URI='http://test.com/'&&set BASE_API_URI='http://testapi.com/'&&set PORT=5000&&webpack-dev-server --host 0.0.0.0`
- remotely when I run:
  `webpack-dev-server --host 0.0.0.0`

Comment: Are you running windows locally? Are you running from a container locally? How are you setting the env variables for heroku?

Comment: Yes, I am running windows locally. For the local run above, I am not running it through a container, but just a local command. I am setting the env variables for heroku through the browser under Config Variables.